# PHP/SQL: 3 tables, one bridge table with a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, sql, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables together: A Contacts table, a Classes table and a StudentsInClasses bridge table that has a one-to-one relationship with Contacts and a one-to-many relationship with Classes.

My desired output is this:

- Peter

  - Math 101
  - French
  - English 202
  - Physics
- Tom Smith

  - French
  - English 202
- Paul

  - English 202
  - Physics
- Harry

  - Math 101
  - Physics

But instead I'm getting this (my var_dump may have different info):

- Peter

  - Math 101
- Tom Smith

  - French
- Paul

  - English 202
- Harry

  - Math 101

Here are my tables StudentsInClasses, Contacts, Classes (sorry for formatting issues, I can't upload pics yet).

StudentsInClassID ContactID ClassID.

1 3 1
2 7 4
3 1 4
4 3 1
5 7 2
6 7 2
7 1 2
11 23 4
10 23 5

ContactID ContactName ContactEmail

1 Peter Homeatgoogledotca
3 Tom Tomhotmaildotcom
7 Paul mehomedotcom
23 Harry Harryhomedotcom

ClassID ClassName ClassRoom

1 Math-101 273
2 English-202 444
4 French 111
5 Physics R444

My SQL Query:

```
$getInfo = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT ClassName, ContactName FROM StudentsInClasses
        JOIN Contacts ON StudentsInClasses.ContactID = Contacts.ContactID
        JOIN Classes ON StudentsInClasses.ClassID = Classes.ClassID
        GROUP BY ContactName");
$getInfo->execute();
$getInfo = $getInfo->fetchAll();
```

My var_dump produces this (you can see I'm only getting a one-to-one relationship with Classes where I should be getting 2-3 classes for each contact):

Harry

```
array(4) { ["ClassName"]=> string(6) "French" [0]=> string(6) "French" ["ContactName"]=> string(5) "Harry" [2]=> string(5) "Harry" }
```

Paul

```
array(4) { ["ClassName"]=> string(11) "English 202" [0]=> string(11) "English 202" ["ContactName"]=> string(9) "Paul" [2]=> string(9) "Paul" }
```

Peter

```
array(4) { ["ClassName"]=> string(11) "English 202" [0]=> string(11) "English 202" ["ContactName"]=> string(5) "Peter" [2]=> string(5) "Peter" }
```

Tom Smith

```
array(4) { ["ClassName"]=> string(8) "Math 101" [0]=> string(8) "Math 101" ["ContactName"]=> string(9) "Tom Smith" [2]=> string(9) "Tom Smith" }
```

Every person should have 2-3 classes, but I'm only getting one.
I've been searching S.O. and Google for a solution, but I'm getting nowhere.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!  8-)